# jQuery: collapse doesn't work on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look to this snippet:

```js
$("document").ready(function () {    
  $("#eth0_mode").change(function () {
    $("#group").find(":input").prop("disabled", this.value === "dhcp");
    $("#group").collapse(this.value === "dhcp" ? "hide" : "show");
  });

  $("#eth0_mode").val("dhcp").trigger("change");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="eth0_mode">
    <option value="dhcp">DHCP</option>
    <option value="fallback">DHCP with fallback</option>
    <option value="static">Static address</option>
  </select>

  <div id="group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="address">
  </div>
</form>
```

On page load it set the value of the select to "dhcp" and triggers the change event.
The event is executed because the input field will be disabled. But the div is not collapsed!

But if you select another item and come back to "dhcp" the div will collapse.

Why?

Comment: I see "script error" message in the snippet window but I don't understand what is the actual error...

Comment: The error is "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js"

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Of course the unexpected behavior is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `collapse` class to the `#group` element to make it work:

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
  $("#eth0_mode").change(function () {
    $("#group").find(":input").prop("disabled", this.value === "dhcp");
    $("#group").collapse(this.value === "dhcp" ? "hide" : "show");
  });

  $("#eth0_mode").val("dhcp").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="eth0_mode">
    <option value="dhcp">DHCP</option>
    <option value="fallback">DHCP with fallback</option>
    <option value="static">Static address</option>
  </select>

  <div id="group" class="collapse show">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="address">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, but in this way the div will be always collapsed, won't it? It's just a case that the first item would require this behavior. It should be up to the change event handler to decide its status.

Comment: In order to use `collapse('hide')` the element must be `collapse show` before. Another option is to set the class to `collapse show` and then the `collapse('hide')` function will work. Updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Note that this way you will get the `hide` animation... not sure if you want that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm not so fast :) I've tried it in the actual environment. I think yours it's an acceptable workaround. The bottom line is Chrome doesn't execute that function? Is there a known reason for that?

Comment: I don't think it's related to chrome. The original code doesn't work in firefox as well... In order to use the `collapse('hide')` you must have the relevant element has the `collapsed` class, and because it's not there - it will work only **after** it was added (using the `show`).